# RuntimeException: Could not dispatch event @ otto

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception, otto

we have an issue in our current app-version with the EventHandler from otto.
We get a `RuntimeException` in our crash-log, with following description:

> "Reason: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not dispatch event:
>   classcom.nameOfBrand.ui.events.SwitchFragmentEvent to handler
>   [EventHandler public void
>   com.nameOfBrand.ui.activities.MainActivity.onSwitchFragmentEvent(com.nameOfBrand.ui.events.SwitchFragmentEvent)]"

We have a button and in its onClickListener we fire an self-defined `SwitchFragmentEvent`.
In some weird situations, the framework can't dispatch the Event and throws an `RuntimeException`.

The fragment with the button extends `AbstractResultListFragment` and this one extends `AbstractFragment`. We register the EventBus in the onResume of AbstractFragement and unregister it at onPause. Everything works fine, except at this one button :/

Does anyone have an idea or had ever to do with something like this?

**UPDATE:**
Scompt was right. The RuntimeException was thrown from otto cause of a NullPointerException in our code. Thx

Tipp: Read your crash-logs until the end ;)

Comment: Do you have any additional information from the exception? There [should be](https://github.com/square/otto/blob/master/otto/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto/Bus.java#L386) a wrapped exception at that point.

Comment: Oh, i see! Have not scrolled so far in the crashlog. In my case it's an NullPointer and as you said, wrapped inside this RuntimeException from the framework. Thanks

Comment: @scompt.com i don't have a wrapped exception. i have a `@Produce` method in my activity where a fragment in my activitie's viewpager is supposed to receive the event. but app clashes with the exception

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There [should be](https://github.com/square/otto/blob/master/otto/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto/Bus.java#L386) a wrapped exception at that point that will provide more information about the crash.

Comment: How are you supposed to use this **protected** method "void dispatch(Object event, EventHandler wrapper)" ?

Comment: How could this be a solution? it links me to a third party method which does not solve anything? I need to solve this problem with more advanced and clear explanation !

Answer (score 1):

If you use with AndroidAnnotation, add `@UiThread` to view treatment method. Note that the method should not be `private`.

Comment: What do you mean `view treatment method`?